# Discrepancy in results from Spark using Broadcasted varaibles

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, gensim, word2vec

I have word2vec model and pyspark job in which I am summing up individual word vectors for each document.

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('w2v.mod')
model2 = sc.broadcast(model)

def getVector(article):
    vec = numpy.ndarray(100)
    for word in article:
        if word in model2.value:
            vec += model2.value[word]
    return vec /len(article)

data = sc.textFile('documents.txt').map(lambda doc:doc.split())
vectors=  data.map(lambda doc:(doc,getVector(doc)))
```

I am getting strange discrepancy between pyspark results and normal results.

```
vectors.take(1)
```

**Results with Spark**

[image: Results with spark]

**Results without spark**
[image: Results without spark]

It just gives me arrays with intensity in dimension of 15 order of magnitude(look at the 7th element above) while computing the same vector locally gives me normal vectors. What is going wrong with using Spark here? Does it mess up answers in communicating the results to Master?